# How to correctly use IFileOperation in Delphi to delete the files in a folder

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to create a simple example of using IFileOperation to delete the files in a
given directory, to include in the answer to another q for comparison with other methods.

Below is the code of my [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It
successfully creates 1000 files in a subdirectory off C:\Temp and then attempts to delete
them in the `DeleteFiles` method.  This supposedly "easy" task fails but I'm not sure
exactly where it comes off the rails.  The comments in the code show what I'm expecting
and the actual results.  On one occasion, instead of the exception noted, I got a pop-up
asking for confirmation to delete an item with an odd name which was evidently an array of
numbers referring to a shell item, but my attempt to capture it using Ctrl-C failed;

I'm fairly sure I'm either missing a step or two, misusing the interfaces involved
or both.  My q is, could anybody please show the necessary corrections to the code to get IFileOperation.DeleteItems() to delete the files in question, as I am completely out of my depth with this stuff?  I am not interested in alternative methods of deleting these files, using the shell interfaces or otherwise.

```
procedure TForm2.DeleteFiles;
var
  iFileOp: IFileOperation;
  iIDList : ItemIDList;
  iItemArray : IShellItemArray;
  iArray : Array[0..1] of ItemIDList;
  Count : DWord;
begin
  iFileOp := CreateComObject(CLSID_FileOperation) as IFileOperation;

  iIDList := ILCreateFromPath(sPath)^;

  //  IFileOperation.DeleteItems seems to require am IShellItemArray, so the following attempts
  //  to create one
  //  The definition of SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists
  //  seems to require a a zero-terminated array of ItemIDLists so the next steps
  //  attempt to create one

  ZeroMemory(@iArray, SizeOf(iArray));
  iArray[0] := iIDList;
  OleCheck(SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists(1, @iArray, iItemArray));

  //  Next test the number of items in iItemArray, which I'm expecting to be 1000
  //  seeing as the CreateFiles routine creats that many

  OleCheck(iItemArray.GetCount(Count));
  Caption := IntToStr(Count);  //  Duh, this shows Count to be 1, not the expected 1000

  OleCheck(iFileOp.DeleteItems(iItemArray));
  OleCheck( iFileOp.PerformOperations );
  // Returns Exception 'No object for moniker'

end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeleteFiles;
end;

procedure CreateFiles;
var
  i : Integer;
  SL : TStringList;
  FileName,
  FileContent : String;
begin

  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if not (DirectoryExists(sPath)) then
      MkDir(sPath);

    SL.BeginUpdate;
    for i := 0 to 999 do begin
      FileName := Format('File%d.Txt', [i]);
      FileContent := Format('content of file %s', [FileName]);
      SL.Text := FileContent;
      SL.SaveToFile(sPath + '\' + FileName);
    end;
    SL.EndUpdate;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateFiles;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are leaking the memory returned by `ILCreateFromPath()`, you need to call `ILFree()` when you are done using the returned `PItemIDList`.

Also, you should not be dereferencing the `PItemIDList`. `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists()` expects an array of `PItemIDList` pointers, but you are giving it an array of `ItemIDList` instances.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.DeleteFiles;
var
  iFileOp: IFileOperation;
  iIDList : PItemIDList;
  iItemArray : IShellItemArray;
  Count : DWord;
begin
  iFileOp := CreateComObject(CLSID_FileOperation) as IFileOperation;

  iIDList := ILCreateFromPath(sPath);
  try
    OleCheck(SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists(1, @iIDList, iItemArray));
  finally
    ILFree(iIDList);
  end;

  //  Next test the number of items in iItemArray, which I'm expecting to be 1000
  //  seeing as the CreateFiles routine creates that many

  OleCheck(iItemArray.GetCount(Count));
  Caption := IntToStr(Count);  //  Duh, this shows Count to be 1, not the expected 1000

  OleCheck(iFileOp.DeleteItems(iItemArray));
  OleCheck( iFileOp.PerformOperations );
  // Returns Exception 'No object for moniker'
end;
```

That being said, even if this were working correctly, you are not creating an `IShellItemArray` containing 1000 `IShellItem`s for the individual files. You are creating an `IShellItemArray` containing 1 `IShellItem` for the `C:\Temp` subdirectory itself.

Which is fine if your goal is to delete the whole folder. But in that case, I would suggest using `SHCreateItemFromIDList()` or `SHCreateItemFromParsingName()` instead, and then pass that `IShellItem` to `IFileOperation.DeleteItem()`.

But, if your goal is to delete the individual files without deleting the subdirectory as well, then you will have to either:

- get the `IShellFolder` interface for the subdirectory, then enumerate the relative PIDLs of its files using `IShellFolder.EnumObjects()`, and then pass the PIDLs in an array to `SHCreateShellItemArray()`.
- get the `IShellFolder` interface of the subdirectory, then query it for an `IDataObject` interface using `IShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf()`, and then use `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject()`, or just give the `IDataObject` directly to `IFileOperation.DeleteItems()`.
- get an `IShellItem` interface for the subdirectory, then query its `IEnumShellItems` interface using `IShellItem.BindToHandler()`, and then pass that directly to `IFileOperation.DeleteItems()`.

Comment: Many thanks, greatly appreciated.  I'll explore your alternative suggestions a bit later, but meanwhile this has obviously answered my q so +1.